# Will a LiveCD with the Nvidia proprietary drivers still work on Intel or AMD graphics?

Tags: nvidia, live-cd

I have installed nvidia proprietary driver on livecd.

Will it break the 3d support for free drivers like intel or radeon etc?

The system is 12.04

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm assuming you've customized a LiveCD with the Nvidia proprietary driver....

**No**, on systems *without* an Nvidia card, the proprietary driver should not break the open-source Intel `i915` or AMD `radeon` driver support. But if you have a hybrid Nvidia "Optimus" laptop, the behavior may be unpredictable.